# How to pass list of sets as separate arguments into function?

Tags: python, list, function, set

I've created a list of sets that I'd like to pass into set.intersection()

For example:

```
List_of_Sets = [{1,2,3},{3,4,5},{5,6,7}]
set.intersection(List_of_Sets)
```

Result:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'intersection' requires a 'set' object but received a 'list'
```

Desired Output:

```
{3,5}
```

How would I pass each set within the list as a separate argument into set.intersection()?

Comment: Please explain the operation you want to implement. `{1,2,3} intersect {3,4,5} intersect {5,6,7}` does not result with `{3,5}` but with `{}`...

Comment: @mgilson I'm not sure about the dups, the answers are identical, but the questions are not.

Comment: @SteinarLima, but then do we allow every unpacking question so long as it applies to a new function?

Comment: @mhlester I don't know. Meta has probably some discussions regarding it.

Comment: @SteinarLima -- I've seen questions closed with less similarity than this before, but as always, my 1 close vote isn't enough.  We still need 4 more ;-).  It's up to the *community* to decide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the unpacking operator:  `set.intersection(*List_of_Sets)`

---

As pointed out in the other answer, you have no intersections in the list.  Do you want to compute the union of the intersection of adjacent elements?

```
>>> set.union(*[x & y for x, y in zip(List_of_Sets, List_of_Sets[1:])])
set([3, 5])
```

Comment: Or, if you *really* like `map` instead:  `set.union(*map(operator.__and__,*zip(List_of_Sets, List_of_Sets[1:])))`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> List_of_Sets = [{1,2,3},{3,4,5},{5,6,7}]
>>> set.intersection(*List_of_Sets)  # * unpacks list into arguments
set([])
```

There are no intersections in that set so it returns an empty set. A working example:

```
>>> List_of_Sets2 = [{1,2,3},{3,4,5},{5,6,3}]
>>> set.intersection(*List_of_Sets2)  # * unpacks list into arguments
set([3])
```

[Docs on unpacking with *](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: Good point on the "There are no intersections" bit.